# sticky position on css grid items

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I've looked at other examples of this on here but can't find one that makes this work. I want the sidebar (section) to be sticky while the page scrolls. the position: sticky works if I put it on the nav, so my browser def supports it.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 55% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr;
}

nav {
  background: blue;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

section {
  background: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

article p {
  padding-bottom: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <section>
    hi
  </section>
  <article>
    <p>hi</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: your sidebar and the navigation bar have to be fixed while the body content must be a normal scrolling div, at least that's what i think you should so to achieve the layout you're going for

Comment: nice, exactly my situation

Answer (score 53):

You need to use `align-self: start` on the thing you want to be `sticky`.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 55% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr;
  background: grey;
}

nav {
  background: blue;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

section {
  background: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  align-self: start;
  
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

article p {
  padding-bottom: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <section>
    hi
  </section>
  <article>
    <p>hi</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Delete the `background: grey` from `main` and see the side effect of your solution: no more equal-height columns, a quite important benefit of CSS Grid.

Comment: It’s an alternate solution, but you’re right.

Comment: I suppose the explicit `top` positioning is also crucial.

Answer (score 44):

the problem you are facing here is, that your section block consumes the full height. so it won't stick, since it is too large to do so. you would need to put a child element inside your section and give that your sticky attributes, to make it work. based on your example, i simply wrapped your 'hi' inside a div.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 55% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr;
  min-height: 1000px;
}

nav {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

section {
  background: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

section div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <section>
    <div>
      <p>one</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <article>
    <p>two</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

EDIT: and here is the reason for the *problem*: elements with `display: grid` have a default attribute for `align-items` to `stretch`, meaning all children have the same height. you can avoid this by setting `align-items: start;` following is another example without the additional div.

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 55% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr;
  min-height: 1000px;
  align-items: start;
}

nav {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

section {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

article p {
  padding-bottom: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <section>
    <p>one</p>
  </section>
  <article>
    <p>two</p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Note that if this isn't working, make sure you don't have a parent element with overflow: hidden. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/how-does-the-position-sticky-property-work

Answer (score 0):

Update with complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 55% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 55px 1fr;
}

nav {
  background: blue;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
}

section {
  background: grey;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fixed-section {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

article {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

article p {
  padding-bottom: 1500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<main>
  <nav></nav>
  <section>
    <div class='fixed-section'>
        <a href="#">Hi 1</a>
    <div>
  </section>
  <article>
    <p>hi</p>
  </article>
</main>
   
</body>
</html>
```