# CSS grid with sticky first row/column?

Tags: css, css-grid

Is it possible to achieve something equivalent to this with a CSS grid?

https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/gWoVzN

i.e. where the first column and/or row of a grid are fixed, and the rest of the grid scrolls horizontally within a wrapper which has `overflow-x: scroll`

EDIT: to clarify, I have tried a number of the examples shown. Specifically, the first column of the grid itself needs to be fixed and the scroll needs to happen within a wrapper element, horizontally. These examples either work vertically or use other html elements.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794795/sticky-position-on-css-grid-items

Comment: yes it is `position:sticky` + `display:grid` example  : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WVXPNP this example uses display:grid on a table .but it could be any other HTML tags

Comment: Hi - I don't think any of those examples do what is needed, and I'm struggling with getting this working with a horizontal scroll where. Have clarified above.