# Sticky column issue with css grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Here's a codepen illustrating the issue: https://codepen.io/robertcooper_rc/pen/jOYbdbR

I'm using a CSS grid to create a table layout. It's been working well, but I'm having an issue with the behavior of `position: sticky` on one of the columns in my grid.

I have a horizontally scrollable table with 4 columns and the first column is sticky.

[image: No scroll]

When I scroll to the right, the first column does stick to the left as is expected.

[image: A bit of scroll to the right]

However, when scrolling starts nearing the end of the table's horizontal space, the first no longer maintains its sticky position to the left edge of the table.

[image: Scrolling all the way to the right]

I've noticed that if I remove the HTML markup for the `<aside>`, the sticky column behavior works as expected. However, I need the `<aside>` to be present.

Any ideas on how to fix this with CSS while maintaining the DOM structure?

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

aside {
  padding-right: 1rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.table {
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    My aside
  </aside>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
      <div class="col">Col 2</div>
      <div class="col">Col 3</div>
      <div class="col">Col 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50794795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem actually falls with the `min-width` set on `.table`. The width is not defined to the end of the row which is affecting the behavior of the sticky elements at row-end.

You'll notice if you exchange `min-width: 0;` to `min-width: 100%;` it functions as you would like, but then the `table` overflows outside of `.container`.

> A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root.

[MDN CSS/Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

So with that said, the elements with the scroll need to have a defined width so the sticky element knows to stay sticky.

A simple solution would be to nest all of the `.table` elements in another wrapper that has a defined width. I chose `300px` based on the rendered width of the content and the container.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

aside {
  padding-right: 1rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.table {
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #eee;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    My aside
  </aside>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col sticky">Col 1</div>
        <div class="col">Col 2</div>
        <div class="col">Col 3</div>
        <div class="col">Col 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!