# Sticky left column with CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid, sticky

### Update:

I found that

```
align-self: start;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

do not work if there is `overflow-x: hidden;` in body or html sections

---

### Original post:

I have existing project where is a header that is not in Grid, and main section with two columns in grid.

How to make my left column sticky when the right is scrollable?
I know here are [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794795/sticky-position-on-css-grid-items) that recommend to [use](https://ishadeed.com/article/position-sticky-css-grid/) `aligh-self: start;` and other things, but they don't work or use different grid; my grid contains only two columns, and header is outside and uses `position: relative;` (maybe here is the problem..)

[Here is link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/Rockietm/pen/JjBwJRY)

```css
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* here is my header that is not in grid */
.header {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 30px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    /* I need relative here because I need sticky menu later */
    position: relative;
}

/* main container for two columns */
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

/* left column */
.author-column {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  
    align-self: start;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

/* right column */
.content-column {
    background-color: aqua;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        HERE IS MY HEADER (OUTSIDE OF THE GRID, FLEX and position:relative;)
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="author-column">

            HERE IS LEFT COLUMN <br /><br />
            I need to be sticky

        </div>
        <div class="content-column">

            HERE IS RIGHT COLUMN
            <br /><br />
            I have data that need to be scrolled
            <br /><br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, molestias rem ducimus deleniti eius suscipit, sed delectus hic cumque, consequatur magnam recusandae quam fugit vel iure repellendus odit eligendi atque.
            Eius laborum adipisci necessitatibus impedit harum velit non laboriosam culpa tempora rerum temporibus blanditiis eum quis exercitationem similique ipsa accusamus minus, architecto praesentium vero cum error. Enim delectus sunt reiciendis?
            Magnam id voluptates dolorum voluptas? Cum tenetur repellat perspiciatis nihil nobis, aliquam sunt fugit nemo doloribus nam perferendis corrupti explicabo eius, eveniet ad optio doloremque, earum minima quo! Quibusdam, dolor?
            Quam iure eum quisquam voluptate cumque adipisci libero in. Earum, est! Odio dolorum minus fugiat magni beatae iusto. Nemo eaque laborum repudiandae adipisci aliquid quibusdam ipsam maiores possimus odit voluptas.
            Fuga culpa harum reiciendis aperiam numquam repellat! Architecto, optio modi magnam recusandae accusamus vitae corrupti quibusdam doloribus autem facilis, totam velit, minima animi? Suscipit reprehenderit perferendis dolores tempore blanditiis repellat.
            Id provident alias praesentium similique nostrum error autem obcaecati voluptas, laboriosam ut totam, officiis nobis nisi dolorem labore deleniti animi eveniet. Perspiciatis pariatur voluptas, velit nihil rerum earum cupiditate totam!
            Repellendus aperiam quidem reiciendis, perferendis sit esse itaque ducimus fuga commodi quisquam eius beatae dolores enim quaerat, velit temporibus mollitia, et neque maxime vitae! Laudantium enim recusandae odit accusamus nostrum.
            Est, magnam! Voluptas amet eligendi facere sint, debitis nihil nisi, in similique ipsum quia perspiciatis suscipit magnam sapiente quod! Molestiae id, soluta reprehenderit voluptatem eius architecto sit iste voluptates quos!
            Molestias asperiores veritatis sit dolore deleniti magnam quod esse culpa quia nesciunt, cupiditate id optio mollitia. Consectetur suscipit ex animi voluptates quis rerum temporibus atque quia repudiandae molestias, ipsa dignissimos.
            Natus dicta sapiente eaque. Dicta, culpa, est voluptate ex ut delectus amet, sunt atque iusto totam distinctio sit. Minus, aperiam! Omnis fuga recusandae earum tempora maxime animi dolores eos expedita!
            Quis nesciunt deserunt ducimus. Nesciunt possimus beatae voluptates numquam pariatur deleniti, ad amet et, nulla porro excepturi quae minus in? Deserunt maxime quos error nostrum perferendis veniam laboriosam incidunt. Sit!
            Quis incidunt pariatur animi error illum harum, commodi dolore dicta iusto aliquam! Unde accusantium porro magnam iste possimus, temporibus assumenda cum illum numquam voluptatibus veniam esse consequatur blanditiis vel aperiam?
            Quasi eveniet, sint ad fuga sit dolorum qui eum provident nostrum beatae magnam officia adipisci quisquam accusamus harum iure! Minus quis unde corrupti eaque nobis! Hic nesciunt neque eius similique.
            Eaque aliquam consequatur libero, dolorem, hic delectus iste aperiam perspiciatis dolores modi error neque quo saepe impedit laborum ipsam provident repellendus animi itaque sunt molestias sit ad facere. Exercitationem, unde.
            Doloremque repellat accusamus sint, est provident impedit iste suscipit reprehenderit quos molestiae omnis, modi autem exercitationem, esse consequuntur ullam adipisci. Dignissimos quidem dicta dolor assumenda quod ullam tenetur aspernatur cum!
            Qui minima odit pariatur, excepturi debitis officiis tempore. Esse omnis enim voluptates minima adipisci? Accusamus voluptatem nisi obcaecati accusantium inventore sequi cumque perspiciatis laborum, vitae perferendis illo, eveniet libero magni.
            Delectus dolore, sunt enim corporis minus nulla facere natus magni aperiam corrupti laboriosam impedit nesciunt reiciendis veritatis cumque. Molestias dolorem deserunt nemo hic delectus debitis expedita a obcaecati aliquid culpa.
            Minus soluta id temporibus iusto esse modi aut sequi neque delectus tempora! Modi, cupiditate. Id distinctio ab deserunt quos atque aliquid explicabo sit laboriosam! Sunt aliquid fugit impedit in culpa!
            Eum labore, neque deleniti nostrum molestias adipisci earum beatae similique eligendi molestiae, doloremque incidunt assumenda cum placeat libero voluptatum asperiores et ea. Fugiat eveniet aliquid impedit id saepe voluptate laudantium.
            Voluptatibus incidunt mollitia vel quidem id dolore, nobis esse facere eum vero, quas architecto! Repudiandae doloremque rerum a accusamus fugiat commodi nemo suscipit quae est deserunt, eos recusandae ipsam atque!
            Impedit illum et enim, natus ea optio expedita tempora inventore suscipit sapiente fugiat, illo, accusantium dolor. Esse adipisci, cupiditate deleniti pariatur natus earum, excepturi inventore laborum dolore quia cum aperiam!
            Recusandae consectetur laborum debitis, facere eaque similique. Laborum placeat velit et adipisci. Doloribus harum quia tempore, dolorum aspernatur facere? Quis quisquam vel quasi voluptatem nam asperiores voluptates corporis, dolore optio!
            Nisi doloremque earum animi, dolor consequatur id vitae quos totam, similique dolorum modi officia blanditiis mollitia eaque sequi voluptate? Quia vel molestias dolore a similique voluptatem vitae temporibus odio eum?
            Quidem, quis nulla earum sequi officiis alias omnis eligendi eum unde excepturi velit, necessitatibus accusantium ratione. Fuga quaerat eius atque quibusdam neque, cumque praesentium ratione doloremque aspernatur, vitae nobis quis!
            Nam fugiat voluptas omnis quam voluptates culpa exercitationem expedita tempora velit eius totam dicta est, consectetur fuga cumque non soluta neque, magni, et consequuntur! Rem nisi molestias optio distinctio! Assumenda?
            Placeat asperiores, eius quos repellat doloremque cum nulla ipsum earum distinctio? Voluptatem delectus libero obcaecati assumenda itaque repellendus laborum dolorem minima numquam reprehenderit, nam cum, odio vero recusandae enim pariatur.
            Cumque debitis adipisci iure sunt odit sapiente labore eos ea, temporibus amet delectus numquam quos error totam voluptate rem iste obcaecati. Non eveniet magni odit ullam eaque vero tempore quisquam.
            Omnis voluptate, voluptatum placeat incidunt exercitationem illo nam molestiae inventore earum cum at! Laboriosam possimus incidunt quasi adipisci fugit inventore neque nulla. Obcaecati atque adipisci eos natus, vitae quas quis.
            Dignissimos iure ratione esse fugiat ipsum totam consequatur praesentium quibusdam aliquid tenetur fuga sunt velit iusto atque minima, illum eius. Animi exercitationem ipsa, vitae veritatis inventore corporis temporibus est quibusdam!
            Ullam eveniet pariatur laborum a, recusandae soluta minima cumque mollitia obcaecati dicta velit corporis ad sapiente facilis assumenda est deserunt harum hic facere, perspiciatis tempore nihil! Odio suscipit omnis quaerat.
            Odit amet architecto aliquam hic eligendi ipsa, earum aperiam? Enim beatae error veritatis magni autem incidunt, necessitatibus, ratione, consequatur fugiat nulla eveniet quam sit fugit magnam voluptatibus quod tempora laborum.
            Maiores voluptate ullam in sint laudantium, sequi, voluptas quidem possimus vitae, reprehenderit tenetur? Corrupti, quibusdam velit molestias tempora eligendi animi eos accusantium ipsa dolore, voluptate sequi nesciunt. Optio, enim ad?
            Ipsa ad, quasi pariatur ipsam deleniti laudantium rerum commodi minima unde, inventore quas sequi praesentium modi nostrum rem soluta consequatur? Non, dolorem maxime at repellat aspernatur possimus consequatur molestiae corrupti.
            Delectus, ab voluptatibus. Expedita ratione pariatur, velit nulla sapiente asperiores. Ullam enim reiciendis quae autem vel harum voluptatibus assumenda necessitatibus. Non possimus culpa magni nihil alias, esse nisi id sit!
            Dignissimos eos optio, ipsa mollitia ab enim ut quia molestiae sint, maiores dolore, consequatur magni. Quo suscipit pariatur quidem quasi, ab tenetur. Hic, explicabo quibusdam sapiente cupiditate debitis expedita molestiae.
            Sit reprehenderit dignissimos quasi ut, quas eos hic corrupti eius, rerum perspiciatis voluptatem sequi aliquid voluptatum repudiandae cumque et harum consequuntur vitae! Aliquam doloremque fuga, modi unde quo dolorem tempore.
            Rem eaque, doloribus dolor deserunt enim, autem minus omnis facilis libero quas voluptates quod quo? Aperiam commodi accusantium, adipisci laudantium amet ducimus quas natus tenetur voluptatum incidunt officiis! Sit, voluptatem?
            Ipsa hic in earum, eveniet ullam incidunt nobis exercitationem quidem, ab nulla labore, eos dignissimos tempore explicabo! Voluptates doloribus praesentium quibusdam, porro ipsa officia reiciendis cum adipisci! Nostrum, aspernatur labore!
            Ipsa alias excepturi harum, qui aliquid rem. Nesciunt eum dicta impedit. Hic, repellat? Ad mollitia beatae neque. Voluptatem sint cum perspiciatis. Iste ducimus quae atque soluta alias saepe libero quos.
            Sit architecto libero deleniti magnam voluptate explicabo animi assumenda ut consequatur suscipit reprehenderit tempore sequi culpa, necessitatibus praesentium cumque quaerat cupiditate! Ullam consectetur cum quo nostrum blanditiis veritatis ab aspernatur.
            Consequuntur cupiditate consequatur mollitia? Dicta sint atque quaerat rerum nobis sapiente, facere nesciunt sit dolorum, odit, voluptas libero! Aliquid, quia reprehenderit consequatur ipsam itaque et hic omnis nihil cum nam?
            Amet maiores tempora molestias. Possimus magni unde rerum assumenda! Illo accusantium harum facere est autem placeat, quis omnis voluptate et a repudiandae laudantium id amet quasi, deserunt laborum qui assumenda?
            Sit, quod quis inventore veritatis incidunt repellendus officiis, autem quibusdam aliquid expedita nam neque perferendis quo alias minima doloribus quasi repellat aspernatur cum soluta in vel consequatur. Debitis, corporis maiores!
            Dolor ipsam blanditiis itaque porro nemo libero eum ut eligendi molestiae id modi illum fugiat similique totam est consectetur ipsum error laborum aut autem quam, minima qui aperiam. Accusantium, magni!
            Architecto, sit deserunt vel consectetur, minima fuga quia id minus aperiam dolorum sunt expedita nostrum! Debitis, velit rerum facilis delectus alias voluptate? Fugiat delectus consequatur obcaecati excepturi dicta ea adipisci.
            Mollitia, dolore quisquam sint nesciunt alias, sed distinctio quaerat inventore possimus amet laborum minima id suscipit laboriosam cumque cupiditate, atque praesentium cum! Ducimus, quod. Quis vero a tempore cupiditate voluptate.
            At autem voluptatum eligendi vero accusamus soluta dicta laudantium, a fugit, repellendus officia, assumenda sapiente saepe sint dolor error. Dolores blanditiis vitae est eos ipsa cupiditate! Hic aperiam doloremque consequuntur!
            Quos, nulla minima. Molestiae ad natus odio ratione. Doloribus autem pariatur facere, sit aperiam aliquam ducimus unde tenetur earum provident! Dolores cum doloribus laudantium perspiciatis voluptatibus. Earum ducimus voluptate necessitatibus.
            Dolor qui sequi nihil, recusandae nulla aspernatur adipisci excepturi placeat odio molestiae iste vitae libero dolores quas blanditiis, tempora hic nobis asperiores ducimus commodi? Perferendis ipsam expedita iure dicta commodi?
            Asperiores culpa beatae esse laborum est, ex itaque dolor officia doloremque velit nesciunt quos provident perspiciatis nihil laudantium eligendi natus nobis minus nisi dolorum porro. Doloremque quos qui iusto incidunt.
            Et inventore repudiandae aperiam ullam, quam non perspiciatis velit itaque, nam, in quas! Ducimus cum aut atque iusto quaerat quos non deleniti accusamus, perferendis quibusdam magnam voluptatem, ullam consequatur sit!
            Vitae laboriosam, eligendi praesentium fugit soluta veritatis asperiores distinctio eos repellendus ducimus enim quis! Architecto aliquid, culpa quia sapiente corporis fugit! Aut similique veritatis saepe eos fuga ex obcaecati magni!
            Alias natus cumque quis tempora nisi minima non facilis error similique, molestiae distinctio quam aliquid assumenda eos officia commodi nihil amet, quisquam, in voluptates veniam. Optio corrupti totam excepturi velit?
            Cumque, nobis? Earum corporis dicta quibusdam tenetur perferendis perspiciatis rerum tempora. Harum maxime, sed atque repellendus ipsa neque quis nulla hic dolorem numquam dignissimos iure reprehenderit laborum, beatae quasi excepturi?
            Nostrum rerum provident eos distinctio tenetur sunt, autem ipsa rem nemo consequuntur voluptatem, amet, tempore similique et? Quidem eveniet ex molestias nostrum blanditiis esse quo saepe, asperiores cupiditate magni dignissimos.
            Tempora nihil dolore porro cum soluta pariatur nostrum nulla ipsum. Doloremque saepe vitae, officia cum libero totam placeat sit beatae odio error ab nostrum architecto non, ipsum commodi temporibus quos!
            Dicta, similique aperiam commodi enim tenetur beatae quos natus sed. Sapiente vitae labore officiis quibusdam, similique voluptate dolore possimus, minima, error quasi voluptates quidem animi iusto quisquam qui ut sequi.
            Facilis quia illo incidunt ipsam rem! Accusamus vel explicabo obcaecati dolor eaque animi sapiente earum ducimus, nam odio nihil, culpa laborum porro, non veritatis atque. Amet aut modi illum laudantium.
            Assumenda optio sint, asperiores magni impedit itaque fuga, sunt accusantium, modi neque voluptate necessitatibus eius placeat? Pariatur laudantium qui ab enim aspernatur explicabo, odit quia, facilis praesentium architecto voluptas quaerat.
            Qui necessitatibus quo aperiam mollitia, adipisci ipsa quibusdam perferendis at in itaque nesciunt quidem incidunt officiis! Eaque maxime dolorem facilis, iure, atque expedita est adipisci possimus aperiam, nostrum sapiente tempore.
            Voluptatibus incidunt mollitia vel quidem id dolore, nobis esse facere eum vero, quas architecto! Repudiandae doloremque rerum a accusamus fugiat commodi nemo suscipit quae est deserunt, eos recusandae ipsam atque!
            Impedit illum et enim, natus ea optio expedita tempora inventore suscipit sapiente fugiat, illo, accusantium dolor. Esse adipisci, cupiditate deleniti pariatur natus earum, excepturi inventore laborum dolore quia cum aperiam!
            Recusandae consectetur laborum debitis, facere eaque similique. Laborum placeat velit et adipisci. Doloribus harum quia tempore, dolorum aspernatur facere? Quis quisquam vel quasi voluptatem nam asperiores voluptates corporis, dolore optio!
            Nisi doloremque earum animi, dolor consequatur id vitae quos totam, similique dolorum modi officia blanditiis mollitia eaque sequi voluptate? Quia vel molestias dolore a similique voluptatem vitae temporibus odio eum?
            Quidem, quis nulla earum sequi officiis alias omnis eligendi eum unde excepturi velit, necessitatibus accusantium ratione. Fuga quaerat eius atque quibusdam neque, cumque praesentium ratione doloremque aspernatur, vitae nobis quis!
            Nam fugiat voluptas omnis quam voluptates culpa exercitationem expedita tempora velit eius totam dicta est, consectetur fuga cumque non soluta neque, magni, et consequuntur! Rem nisi molestias optio distinctio! Assumenda?
            Placeat asperiores, eius quos repellat doloremque cum nulla ipsum earum distinctio? Voluptatem delectus libero obcaecati assumenda itaque repellendus laborum dolorem minima numquam reprehenderit, nam cum, odio vero recusandae enim pariatur.
            Cumque debitis adipisci iure sunt odit sapiente labore eos ea, temporibus amet delectus numquam quos error totam voluptate rem iste obcaecati. Non eveniet magni odit ullam eaque vero tempore quisquam.
            Omnis voluptate, voluptatum placeat incidunt exercitationem illo nam molestiae inventore earum cum at! Laboriosam possimus incidunt quasi adipisci fugit inventore neque nulla. Obcaecati atque adipisci eos natus, vitae quas quis.
            Dignissimos iure ratione esse fugiat ipsum totam consequatur praesentium quibusdam aliquid tenetur fuga sunt velit iusto atque minima, illum eius. Animi exercitationem ipsa, vitae veritatis inventore corporis temporibus est quibusdam!
            Ullam eveniet pariatur laborum a, recusandae soluta minima cumque mollitia obcaecati dicta velit corporis ad sapiente facilis assumenda est deserunt harum hic facere, perspiciatis tempore nihil! Odio suscipit omnis quaerat.
            Odit amet architecto aliquam hic eligendi ipsa, earum aperiam? Enim beatae error veritatis magni autem incidunt, necessitatibus, ratione, consequatur fugiat nulla eveniet quam sit fugit magnam voluptatibus quod tempora laborum.
            Maiores voluptate ullam in sint laudantium, sequi, voluptas quidem possimus vitae, reprehenderit tenetur? Corrupti, quibusdam velit molestias tempora eligendi animi eos accusantium ipsa dolore, voluptate sequi nesciunt. Optio, enim ad?
            Ipsa ad, quasi pariatur ipsam deleniti laudantium rerum commodi minima unde, inventore quas sequi praesentium modi nostrum rem soluta consequatur? Non, dolorem maxime at repellat aspernatur possimus consequatur molestiae corrupti.
            Delectus, ab voluptatibus. Expedita ratione pariatur, velit nulla sapiente asperiores. Ullam enim reiciendis quae autem vel harum voluptatibus assumenda necessitatibus. Non possimus culpa magni nihil alias, esse nisi id sit!
            Dignissimos eos optio, ipsa mollitia ab enim ut quia molestiae sint, maiores dolore, consequatur magni. Quo suscipit pariatur quidem quasi, ab tenetur. Hic, explicabo quibusdam sapiente cupiditate debitis expedita molestiae.
            Sit reprehenderit dignissimos quasi ut, quas eos hic corrupti eius, rerum perspiciatis voluptatem sequi aliquid voluptatum repudiandae cumque et harum consequuntur vitae! Aliquam doloremque fuga, modi unde quo dolorem tempore.
            Rem eaque, doloribus dolor deserunt enim, autem minus omnis facilis libero quas voluptates quod quo? Aperiam commodi accusantium, adipisci laudantium amet ducimus quas natus tenetur voluptatum incidunt officiis! Sit, voluptatem?
            Ipsa hic in earum, eveniet ullam incidunt nobis exercitationem quidem, ab nulla labore, eos dignissimos tempore explicabo! Voluptates doloribus praesentium quibusdam, porro ipsa officia reiciendis cum adipisci! Nostrum, aspernatur labore!
            Ipsa alias excepturi harum, qui aliquid rem. Nesciunt eum dicta impedit. Hic, repellat? Ad mollitia beatae neque. Voluptatem sint cum perspiciatis. Iste ducimus quae atque soluta alias saepe libero quos.
            Sit architecto libero deleniti magnam voluptate explicabo animi assumenda ut consequatur suscipit reprehenderit tempore sequi culpa, necessitatibus praesentium cumque quaerat cupiditate! Ullam consectetur cum quo nostrum blanditiis veritatis ab aspernatur.
            Consequuntur cupiditate consequatur mollitia? Dicta sint atque quaerat rerum nobis sapiente, facere nesciunt sit dolorum, odit, voluptas libero! Aliquid, quia reprehenderit consequatur ipsam itaque et hic omnis nihil cum nam?
            Amet maiores tempora molestias. Possimus magni unde rerum assumenda! Illo accusantium harum facere est autem placeat, quis omnis voluptate et a repudiandae laudantium id amet quasi, deserunt laborum qui assumenda?
            Sit, quod quis inventore veritatis incidunt repellendus officiis, autem quibusdam aliquid expedita nam neque perferendis quo alias minima doloribus quasi repellat aspernatur cum soluta in vel consequatur. Debitis, corporis maiores!
            Dolor ipsam blanditiis itaque porro nemo libero eum ut eligendi molestiae id modi illum fugiat similique totam est consectetur ipsum error laborum aut autem quam, minima qui aperiam. Accusantium, magni!
            Architecto, sit deserunt vel consectetur, minima fuga quia id minus aperiam dolorum sunt expedita nostrum! Debitis, velit rerum facilis delectus alias voluptate? Fugiat delectus consequatur obcaecati excepturi dicta ea adipisci.
            Mollitia, dolore quisquam sint nesciunt alias, sed distinctio quaerat inventore possimus amet laborum minima id suscipit laboriosam cumque cupiditate, atque praesentium cum! Ducimus, quod. Quis vero a tempore cupiditate voluptate.
            At autem voluptatum eligendi vero accusamus soluta dicta laudantium, a fugit, repellendus officia, assumenda sapiente saepe sint dolor error. Dolores blanditiis vitae est eos ipsa cupiditate! Hic aperiam doloremque consequuntur!
            Quos, nulla minima. Molestiae ad natus odio ratione. Doloribus autem pariatur facere, sit aperiam aliquam ducimus unde tenetur earum provident! Dolores cum doloribus laudantium perspiciatis voluptatibus. Earum ducimus voluptate necessitatibus.
            Dolor qui sequi nihil, recusandae nulla aspernatur adipisci excepturi placeat odio molestiae iste vitae libero dolores quas blanditiis, tempora hic nobis asperiores ducimus commodi? Perferendis ipsam expedita iure dicta commodi?
            Asperiores culpa beatae esse laborum est, ex itaque dolor officia doloremque velit nesciunt quos provident perspiciatis nihil laudantium eligendi natus nobis minus nisi dolorum porro. Doloremque quos qui iusto incidunt.
            Et inventore repudiandae aperiam ullam, quam non perspiciatis velit itaque, nam, in quas! Ducimus cum aut atque iusto quaerat quos non deleniti accusamus, perferendis quibusdam magnam voluptatem, ullam consequatur sit!
            Vitae laboriosam, eligendi praesentium fugit soluta veritatis asperiores distinctio eos repellendus ducimus enim quis! Architecto aliquid, culpa quia sapiente corporis fugit! Aut similique veritatis saepe eos fuga ex obcaecati magni!
            Alias natus cumque quis tempora nisi minima non facilis error similique, molestiae distinctio quam aliquid assumenda eos officia commodi nihil amet, quisquam, in voluptates veniam. Optio corrupti totam excepturi velit?
            Cumque, nobis? Earum corporis dicta quibusdam tenetur perferendis perspiciatis rerum tempora. Harum maxime, sed atque repellendus ipsa neque quis nulla hic dolorem numquam dignissimos iure reprehenderit laborum, beatae quasi excepturi?
            Nostrum rerum provident eos distinctio tenetur sunt, autem ipsa rem nemo consequuntur voluptatem, amet, tempore similique et? Quidem eveniet ex molestias nostrum blanditiis esse quo saepe, asperiores cupiditate magni dignissimos.
            Tempora nihil dolore porro cum soluta pariatur nostrum nulla ipsum. Doloremque saepe vitae, officia cum libero totam placeat sit beatae odio error ab nostrum architecto non, ipsum commodi temporibus quos!
            Dicta, similique aperiam commodi enim tenetur beatae quos natus sed. Sapiente vitae labore officiis quibusdam, similique voluptate dolore possimus, minima, error quasi voluptates quidem animi iusto quisquam qui ut sequi.
            Facilis quia illo incidunt ipsam rem! Accusamus vel explicabo obcaecati dolor eaque animi sapiente earum ducimus, nam odio nihil, culpa laborum porro, non veritatis atque. Amet aut modi illum laudantium.
            Assumenda optio sint, asperiores magni impedit itaque fuga, sunt accusantium, modi neque voluptate necessitatibus eius placeat? Pariatur laudantium qui ab enim aspernatur explicabo, odit quia, facilis praesentium architecto voluptas quaerat.
            Qui necessitatibus quo aperiam mollitia, adipisci ipsa quibusdam perferendis at in itaque nesciunt quidem incidunt officiis! Eaque maxime dolorem facilis, iure, atque expedita est adipisci possimus aperiam, nostrum sapiente tempore.
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: you are not applying any sticky CSS. using `align-self: start;
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;` on your left column does the job. The header is irrelevant to your problem

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank You for response! You helped to resolve. Strange, it really worked in demo example, but I found the problem in production. I had overflow-x: hidden; in body in html styles. In this case it does not work. Updated Codepen.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806576/8620333

Comment: Thank You @TemaniAfif. auto stil does not work for me, but I simply commented overflow-x , thank You!