# "sticky" Angular Material toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

I'm building an Angular web app with a menu that has lots of categories. I would like something similar to a toolbar that will be "sticky" at the top once the user scrolls past the app.component.html standard navigation items.

Here is how it looks before you scroll.

After the user scrolls down I would like the purple toolbar to become "sticky" and stick to the top. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Material does some sneaky things with hiding overflow. Use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47878455/9042495) to answer question