# Position "sticky" not working in ReactJS app, and no "overflow" attribute specified in parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sticky

I'm building a React app, and I'm having a problem with `position: sticky` in my `story-header` element. I already checked the parent styles and there's no `overflow: hidden` attribute-value.

HTML

```
<div className='StoryList' >
    <div className='story-header'></div>
</div>
```

CSS - Stylesheet

```
.App {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
.StoryList {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.story-header {
    width: 100%;
    top: -20px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Why is the `story-header` sliding above the top?**

Comment: You might find some useful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/position-sticky-not-working-css-and-html/47878455

Comment: you added a negative value for top

Comment: @TemaniAfif I did. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood you correctly, but it works as it should. I've tried it in pure html/css and it's working. Check my code, buddy:

```
.App {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200vh;
    overflow: visible;
}

.StoryList {
    background: #000;
    height: 40vh;
    position: fixed; // you can comment it out, I'm not sure what would you like to have
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.story-header {
    width: 100%;
    top: -20px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Check both versions - with fixed position and without it.

Answer (score 1):

well i am also having the same problem turns out i need to set the height of the app and root to inherit, trying doing it and it should work then

Comment: Please be more precise, add your code. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

It is may be very strange, but in my case the deleting of the font-size: 100%; and the font-size: inherit; in the zero-styles helped me to solve the issue!