# Sticky element is not sticking at the specified position

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sticky, floating

I just found that a sticky element won't work as expected if the succeeding element is a floating element.

for example, look at the following HTML code,

<div style="position:sticky"> 
tto 
</div>

<div style="float:left; padding-bottom: 3000px">
blah
</div>

In such cases, the sticky elements will scroll along with the first succeeding non-floating element's bottom part.
If anyone ever faced the same situation or knows a solution please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "position: sticky;" property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/how-does-the-position-sticky-property-work)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use floats -

```
<div style="position:sticky;top:0">
tto
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-bottom: 3000px">
blah
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div> //extra div needed
```

You must also specify at least one of `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left` for sticky positioning to work.

If you want to know more about float - [All about floats](https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/42-all-about-floats-screencast/)

**Else**

Instead of using float try using [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as FlexBox gives you the layout benefits of floats, without the strange quirks and hacks.

Comment: This small code is working. But my original website is a little large. I am not able to fix the problem there. https://fulgid-distortions.000webhostapp.com/      look this, there is a menu at the beginning. which is a sticky element with top: 0;    Still it is not staying at the top..I tried clear:both to every div tag near it..still problem is not fixed.

Comment: add <div style="clear:both;"></div> after div with id="underconstruction" .This should make the div sticky

Answer (score 0):

Hellooo,

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sticky">
tto
</div>
<div style="float:left; padding-bottom: 3000px">
blah
</div>
</div>

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

This is working somehow. Apparently adding a container helps. Can you let me know if this is working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please edit your anwser to fulfill the SO guidelines. SO is about teaching and explainging a solution so it will be reproducable. Providing a code snipept withotu any explanation of what you did, why you did it and how it work is insufficient for SO.