# Make a position fixed div scroll with other contents when scroll hit certain point of page

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have this setup.
[image]

I need this yellow sticky box to be position fixed until the scroll reaches the footer. when the footer hits the screen, the sticky box should scroll with the dynamic content box and vise versa. I tried `position: sticky` but no luck. javascript solutions will be also OK.

I also tried the below code also, but it will not work smoothly, since `position: relative` makes the sticky-content-box jump directly to the top, not scroll with the left side content.

```
const height = 900; // this would be calculated dynamic content box height

const backGroundAnimation = useCallback(() => {
    if (window.scrollY > height) {
      fixedBox!.current!.style.position = 'relative';
      fixedBox!.current!.style.marginTop = `${height}px`;
    } else {
      fixedBox!.current!.style.position = 'fixed';
    }
  }, [height]);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', backGroundAnimation);

    return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', backGroundAnimation);
  }, [backGroundAnimation]);
```

here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-williams-xvdvg?file=/src/App.tsx) setup I have

please note that with the `codesandbox` implementation I did not include the functions I added here in the question.

Comment: I think you want to detach yellow part from footer and want it to stay relative only to red part. You can set `zIndex:-10` so the yellow content will go behind footer and no longer hide footer content.

Comment: it's not attached to the footer, red part and yellow part are relative elements

Answer (score 1):

I have checked issue which you are facing and the solution is very simple you don't need to use javascript for it. You can just use css `position:sticky`.

```
import "./styles.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ height: "80px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
        top navigation
      </div>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row">
          <div
            className="col-sm-8"
            style={{ height: "900px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
          >
            dynamic content
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                height: "200px",
                top:"0",
                backgroundColor: "yellow",
                width: "100%"
              }}
            >
              sticky content
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style={{ height: "400px", backgroundColor: "blue" }}>footer</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

in above code i have just updated this css:

```
style={{
  position: "sticky",
  top:"0",
  height: "200px",
  backgroundColor: "yellow",
   width: "100%"
}}
```

---

How `position:sticky` exactly works can be found here: [How does the "position: sticky;" property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/how-does-the-position-sticky-property-work)

Comment: this is not working, I mentioned that in the question also.

Comment: It is working fine, for reference i am sharing the the demo with you

i have used the HTML source of your JSX code
[ https://codepen.io/kukrati/pen/XWaYWEx ]

Comment: I see the issue now, I did not add `top` value. it's needed to behave position sticky. BTW I just created it to recreate my problem with production code. In my production code this is not working, can't seem to find the issue though. That's why I am looking for a javascript solution. Thanks for your time to answer this