# Position sticky wont work in current layout

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky

I have a react app with 2 divs within a wrapper. The first div 'product-images' has a child div called 'product-info' in it that needs to stick to the top of the parent and span about 80vh in height - it should cover the viewport. I have other child elements within this div that i want the sticky position to be overlayed on top of. Once the 1st div is scrolled and 2nd div comes in I want the sticky div to be contained within 'product-images' however it won't stick! Can't figure out why.

I need a solution where the the rest of the children treat the sticky like a fixed div and ignore it from the flow letting product info be an overlay until it reaches the end of that container.

here is the way my html is setup -

```css
.product-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80vw;
}

.product-images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* max-width: 80vw; */
  /* text-align: center; */
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  /* position relative; */
  /*   overflow: scroll; */
}

.product-img {
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 1rem 0rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.product-images img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-info {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 80dvh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 0;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-images">
  <div class="product-info">
    <!--   this is the sticky one     -->
    <div class="product-top_row">
      <div className="product-text">
        <p>Title</p>
        <p>type</p>
        <p>price</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-btm_row">
      <ProductForm />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div key={img.node.src} class="product-img">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x600/png" style={{  width:'auto', height: '100%' }} />
  </div>
  <div key={img.node.src} class="product-img">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x600/png" style={{  width:'auto', height: '100%' }} />
  </div>
  <div key={img.node.src} class="product-img">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x600/png" style={{  width:'auto', height: '100%' }} />
  </div>
  <div key={img.node.src} class="product-img">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/400x600/png" style={{  width:'auto', height: '100%' }} />
  </div>
  <Link href='/shop' class='backbtn'>Back to Products</Link>
</div>
<div class='description'>
  <div class="innertext">
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is. working code pen : https://codepen.io/laiqa-mohid/pen/OJdjbbm

Comment: The parent needs to be `position:relative` and needs to have an overflow to cause scrolling.  See this question: [How does the "position: sticky;" property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/how-does-the-position-sticky-property-work)

Comment: Your demo will not work because `className` is not a standard HTML property, that something specific to whatever library you are using.

Comment: ok i will change it

Comment: it doesn't work in my code for some reason

Comment: Here is the working site - https://trance-party-net.vercel.app/shop/laeebs-dream-t-shirt

Comment: if you inspect it i applied the changes to it but it won't work :/

Comment: So in your codepen demo the "title type price" seems to stick to the top when scrolling. I am not seeing a problem at all.  Does that properly demonstrate the issue you are having?

Comment: Yeah it works in the codepen but not in my actual site  - if you could inspect the code in the site link i posted would be v appreciated. Not sure why it won't work irl

Comment: I've copied your codepen code to this question so people don't have to go off and view two different external websites just to see what this is talking about.  Please make a code sample that reproduces the issue you are having. I am unclear about what is supposed to be sticky or not on your website.  Your code sample works, but it looks nothing like your website.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.