# How do I make the footer stick to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer

For some reason, it only works on the home page. Any suggestions? One more thing, the site is here: https://captainsapphire.github.io/
(Ignore the other issues for right now).

```css
#footer-container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #1D3557;
  color: #E63946;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
}

footer address {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

#footer-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <footer id="footer-container">
    <address>mpharry9999@gmail.com</address>
    <a href="https://www.artfol.co/captain_sapphire" target="_blank"><img src="https://github.com/CaptainSapphire/captainsapphire.github.io/blob/main/images/artfollogo.png?raw=true" id="footer-image"></a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please more describe your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "position: sticky;" property work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707076/how-does-the-position-sticky-property-work)

Answer (score 2):

I saw your code, if you add ***bottom: 0px;*** and ***position: fixed;*** to footer style, your footer will stick to the bottom of the page.

```css
#footer-container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

footer {
  background-color: #1D3557;
  color: #E63946;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

footer address {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

#footer-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <footer id="footer-container">
    <address>mpharry9999@gmail.com</address>
    <a href="https://www.artfol.co/captain_sapphire" target="_blank"><img src="https://github.com/CaptainSapphire/captainsapphire.github.io/blob/main/images/artfollogo.png?raw=true" id="footer-image"></a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help, I removed `position: absolute` from **#footer-container** and added `margin-top: auto` to push it to the bottom and I edited some padding values.

```css
#footer-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #1D3557;
  color: #E63946;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

footer address {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

#footer-image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-container">
    <address>mpharry9999@gmail.com</address>
    <a href="https://www.artfol.co/captain_sapphire" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://github.com/CaptainSapphire/captainsapphire.github.io/blob/main/images/artfollogo.png?raw=true" id="footer-image">
    </a>
</div>
```